# Check for username and password always return false

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on a login form in C# where I am using WPF, and I have made a check to see if the data in the form is valid but for some reason it always returns false.

For context here is my check:

```
private bool CanExecuteLoginCommand(object obj)
{
    bool validData;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username) || Username.Length < 3 || Password == null || Password.Length < 3)
        validData = false;
    else
        validData = true;
    return validData;
}
```

Does anyone know what is causing it to always return false even though username and password is more than three characters?

I have tried setting the username and password so they are both more than three characters and where expecting it to return true.

Comment: If you debug your `if` statement, what are the values for `Username` and `Password`? 
Are these properties correctly set?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, the problem was that I forgot to return username and password in these methods

```
    public string Username 
        { 
            get { return _username; }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
            }
        }
        public string Password 
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code is not entirely correct: you're raising the `OnPropertyChanged` event in every property-setter, even if the value hasn't actually changed - you should only raise the event when the value changes.

Comment: The code could perhaps be more efficient, but it is of course "correct". Nothing wrong happens (or even nothing at all) when you raise the event although the property value has not actually changed.

Answer (score -1):

You're not using the `obj` argument and did not include the `Username` or `Password` declarations. Did you mean to do `obj.Username` instead?

Comment: The type `object` does not have a Username property or field, so `obj.Username` will not compile. Besides that, we can safely assume that OP is not at all using the `parameter` argument of the Execute and CanExecute methods of the ICommand interface.